# Trouble with ipython notebook after upgrading ubuntu to 17.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, upgrade

I recently upgraded ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.10. 
Afterwards, when I try

```
sudo pip install jupyter

graphlab-create 2.1 has requirement decorator==4.0.9, but you'll have decorator 4.3.0 which is incompatible.
graphlab-create 2.1 has requirement requests==2.9.1, but you'll have requests 2.18.1 which is incompatible.

Cannot uninstall 'pyzmq'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

When I try running

```
ipython notebook
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 445, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate virtualenv and install Jupyter there. If you still face the same error, downgrade pip. I am assuming you are having pip version 10. You can downgrade by doing `pip install pip==9.0.1`. Try installing Jupyter now.

If you don't want to downgrade pip, you have to manually remove all those packages, `pyzmq` in this case, from `site-packages` directory before installing Jupyter.

Reference: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247